# What happens when creating string in smalltalk?

Tags: object, smalltalk

I am noobie in Smalltak, but I need to understand some things for my thesis. What is exactly happening when creating string or any other object? For example, lets do this:

```
fruit <- 'apple'
```

When I try to inspect object fruit, I see it has 5 inst vars. If I had assigned 'pear' to fruit, it would have had 4 inst vars. So interpreter created new instance of bytestring, added required inst vars for every character and assigned them with proper values? I believe there is something more going on, but I can't find it anywhere and I don't have time to properly learn smalltalk. Can you explain it to me, or give me some link where I can find it?

Comment: ' I don't have time to properly learn smalltalk.: Why are you looking at smalltalk then?

Comment: I need it for my school thesis. I'm doing something like comparison of some part of few programming languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings are objects. Objects contain instance variables and respond to messages.  In Smalltalk there are basically two kinds of instance variables: named instance variables are referenced by name (like name or phoneNumber in a Person object) and indexed instance variables are referenced by numbers.  String uses indexed instance variables.

Consider the following example:

```
fruit := String new: 5.
fruit at: 1 put: $a;
    at: 2 put: $p;
    at: 3 put: $p;
    at: 4 put: $l;
    at: 5 put: $e.
```

This creates a String with space for 5 characters. It then gets the fruit variable to point to that object. Then it writes 5 characters into the string. The result is the string 'apple'.

Since Strings are so commonly used, the compiler supports a special syntax to create strings at compile time.

```
fruit := 'apple'
```

In this example, 'apple' is a String literal. The Smalltalk compiler creates the string when it compiles the line.  When you run the line, you will make fruit point to the string 'apple' which has 5 indexed instance variables containing Character objects.

Comment: Niggling pedantic question David... In the case of byte indexable object, do you still think it is correct to refer to them as in indexed instance variables. Are the "bytes" found in byte indexable object truly objects? You can fetch objects (characters and numbers) that represent them, but they're not the same as those bytes. IOW, 'Apple' represents one object that the memory manager has to worry about, not 1 + 5. This of course is past the "entry level" explanation.

Comment: Yes they are implemented in a different way, but the outward appearance to a Smalltalk programmer is that they behave like objects. It doesn't matter how the language implementer chose to represent the data.  If it looks like an object and behaves like an object then it's an object.  I've heard it said that with computer languages, you can cheat so long as you don't get caught. If you gave me a fake tree that was indistinguishable from a real tree in all respects, then I'll still call it a tree.  How's that for metaphysics?

Answer (score 4):

They're not instance variables, they're positions in an indexable object, pretty similar to what happens when you create an Array or any other kind of collection.

A String, in Smalltalk, is just a Collection of Characters, where each Character is stored in the position it occupies inside the String.

Some examples to get you acquainted with Strings being just like Arrays:

```
'Good Morning' at: 3.
#(1 'hi' $d 5.34) at: 3.

'Good Morning' fourth.
#(1 'hi' $d 5.34) fourth.

'Good Morning' reversed.
#(1 'hi' $d 5.34) reversed.

'Good Morning' select: [ :each | each ~= $d ].
#(1 'hi' $d 5.34) select: [ :each | each ~= $d ].
```

As you can see, Strings are just another kind of Collection.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are indexable objects, which means that they are arrays and the slots are numbered instead of "labeled" ...

Answer (score 2):

First thing, is that an expression which you giving as an example does not creates a string.
It is simple assignment.

```
fruit := 'apple'
```

does not creates a string. It assigns existing string 'apple' to fruit variable.
If you want to create new strins, you should use
(Byte)String new: 
similar to
Array new: ..

This is how compiler actually creating the new strings when compiling source code.

Comment: But the 'apple' string does not exist before the compiler started to treat the statement? And I mean including parsing of course

Comment: The use of single-quotation marks does indeed create an instance of a ByteString (a specialized subclass of String) as can easily be seen by evaluating `'foobar' class name.` which, when printed, will result in the symbol `#ByteString`.